# Delphi & Pascal Code

Tags: delphi, pascal

Привет Всем!
Есть файл : editME.exe
Этот файл имеет label,с текстом 54321.
Код в Pascal Source

> data: array[0..5] of byte = (    $8B,
> $44, $24, $30, $C7, $40 );

Надо место этого текста записать текст из edit1.
Delphi 7.

Comment: Вы, видимо, декомпилировали программу в Паскаль. Что именно Вы хотите сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, `edit1.text` имеет тип `String`. Нужно поменять тип переменной `data` на `String`, чтобы присвоить ей значение из `edit1.text`, но это может повлиять на другой код, использующий эту переменную.

Comment: А как это сделать,изучаю делфи месяц только. Большинство непонятно )

Comment: Странно, что Вы начали с попытки редактирования существующей программы (editME.exe). Декомпиляция дело сложное, тем более с последующей редакцией. Начните с написания своих программ.